# Best, and acceptable, connector for 12 to 20 ground wires in a junction box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, junction-box, grounding-and-bonding

In a junction box with about 12, and may grow to 20, cables of size #14, #12, #10 what is the best, and alternative connectors to join all the ground wires together?

- Can I install a ground block, the kind used in a breaker panel, screwed directly to the box using its designed threaded ground terminal hole, IE the "green screw" hole?

[image]

- I have seen electricians use a big ground *rod* clamp to do this, and just shove all the grounds into it.  I don't know if this is ok, and/or if they all must also be twisted together?  Twisting 20 wires together seems painful to maintain.  It's also possible what I saw was not a ground rod clamp, but a special clamp designed for this purpose?  But I don't think I've seen one and shudder to ask what might become a shopping question.

[image]

- a huge wire nut?   I think they make them this big.  I have no intention of using one but it seems like a good answer should mention the pros if there are any.  The cons seem obvious.  Twisting 20 wires strongly together will be a maintenance nightmare.

I realize that typically large splice boxes are in commercial installations using metal conduit where this problem doesn't exist.  And so this problem is relatively rare in residential, but it must come up often enough to have a "best practice"?

Comment: I would imagine the ground block would be the best.  The ease of adding and removing a ground wire any time should outlay any other options.

Comment: Just a note, worked many commercial jobs where even with metal conduit ground wires were in the specs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could hang 4 (or more)  "greenie" wire nuts off a wire connected to the ground screw. The greenies have a hole for one wire to pass through, as they are only for ground connections. Then you can twist on as many as their capacity allows. If the pass-through wire continues to another greenie, you can do that again.

But an accessory ground bar probably makes sense for what box fill calculations say should be a rather large junction box.

Third option which I hate as it's not suited for ever changing anything (but then, how often do you change grounds in a junction box, other than to add one) is crimp sleeves, but then you need a crimper and the correct dies for it.

Comment: Tending towards accepting this answer because it confirms my first choice (ground bar) is viable and adds IMO a great second choice with the pass-through nuts.  Just hoping to confirm there isn't an issue of bus-bar listings being specific to certain boxes. It seems silly to ask, but can a brand-specific EG Murray bus bar be used in a random NEMA enclosure?

Comment: @jay613 -- you can't use a ground bar from a panelboard in a random NEMA box.  You instead need a ground bar with a standalone UL 467 (KDER) listing, which isn't easy to find.  (The Ilsco NBAS and NBAE series bars are your best bet, at least as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 8):

I have installed a ground bar before, really didn't seem worth the effort or cost. Went back to just daisy-chaining wingnuts.

Never seen a big clamp that resembled a ground rod clamp listed for the purpose.

Early in my career I tried to jam like 8 or more wires into a big blue 454 wingnut, could pretty easily pull one of the center wires out. Later I became aware of the UL chart on the box, for wire size #12, 6 max, for wire size #22, also 6 max. There really is a mechanical issue that limits the ability to grip more than 6 wires.

Comment: I suspect the maximum of 6 has to do with the fact that with 7 (or, very likely, with more) wires, they'll naturally pack together such that the central wire is only held in place by the other wires, and isn't held by the nut itself.  This is true even if all the wires are twisted together

Comment: @ChrisH Which takes you one of my favourite websites: _The best known packings of equal circles in a circle (complete up to N = 2600)_ hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/d1.html

Answer (score 5):

With a 5-position Wago™ or wire nut capable of handling 5 wires, connect 4 grounds and a pig-tail. Then run that pig-tail to the next connector, 3 ground wires, and another pig-tail.

Group wires by size using appropriately sized connectors and pig-tails between size groups of the smaller size since grounds can be smaller (I believe) since they're not carrying constant current.

Lather. Rinse. Repeat until all grounds are connected.

This has got to be a mighty large junction box!

---

Use a small panel with the bus bars removed. If screwing a ground block to the panel works at a main/sub panel, it would have to work here.

This would be an ideal use for a small 6-12 space panel, possibly with the addition of a second ground bar.

Comment: It's an 8x6x4 box with 14 knockouts for $20.  Can't beat that.  Plenty of space.  I'm using Wago 221s for all the  current-carrying conductors.  In past projects I've chained them together but trying to avoid it for this one.  With 12+ grounds I think a ground bar is neater,  IMO easier, and only  a few bucks more.   I also don't have to worry about grouping or chaining wire sizes correctly as you wisely described.

Comment: See, @jay613, I resisted VtC for "best" because you're not new here. I shoulda known better... :)

Comment: I should have known better than to use "best".  :)     But I think it's reasonable to use the word when asking for the objective or exhaustive pros and cons of a small number of solutions to a very narrow problem.   I think spelling that out to the group of people capable of answering would just add noise.

Comment: If I *was* going to chain things, I like @ecnerwal's suggestion of chaining greeen pass-through twist connectors.  I would attach a long #10 to the box and use *that* as the "bus" for all the connectors.  While I don't like twisting, this avoids the problem you highlighted about cascading the wire sizes correctly.